# Using Vue 2 SSR and Vuex, how do I update data client side?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, server-side-rendering

I am successfully using Vue 2 and Vuex on the server, I have a store that is working for functions in mounted().

However, when I want the user to be able to update things the store is undefined as it isn't on the client. How do I change this?

In my current scenario I am using the vuex store to hold 'search' text, which I use to show a grid of items based on the search text. That works fine serverside but as soon as I want the user to be able to type into the search box to change it, it does not work.

This is what I want to do:

```
<template>
    <input type="search" class="search"  :value="$store.state.search" @input="changeSearch">
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'search-bar',
    methods: {
        changeSearch: (event) => this.$store.commit('SET_SEARCH', event.target.value)
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that changing `:value` to `v-model` has made it work. Not sure if that is the best answer but glad to have sorted it for now.